# Android app upload picture to Instagram

Tags: android, instagram

**Question:**

It is possible to upload photo from Android App to Instagram?

Some says its not possible because of this http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/

I just want to clarify if it is possible or not. If not possible if there another way on how to upload photo to instagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not really possible. The Instagram API only supports the retrieval of data (as you can see based on all of those GETs).

There really are no alternatives either since Instagram doesn't want to let other people have this type of functionality (otherwise we would see a ton of knockoff Instagram apps).

Comment: I concur this.  The days of having an app that can post publicly on behalf of the user are numbered.

Comment: @danny117 Yeah it's too bad because there really are a lot of cool and creative ideas that people have for things like Instagram but the API's aren't open enough to allow it.